# Longest Odd/Even Sequence in Composite Patterns

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, prime-numbers

**NOTE** I have completely reworded this because I made a complete hash of it the first time, it got worse as I added to it. I apologize to anyone who might have been confused, and hope that this will be seen as a better attempt. Also, I'm not a (proper) mathematician so my terminology can be a little unconventional in places.

I have been investigating the Goldbach Strong Conjecture and have come up against a problem for which I can't find any references.

My approach  is to prove that for any number in any given range of numbers there will be at least one pair of primes equidistant from it. I am attempting to do this (and have obviously not succeeded) by looking at the longest possible sequence of composites either side of a given number, regardless of whether that sequence is practically possible or not within the given range.

For an even number, the odd composites and primes will be an odd +ve or -ve offset from it. E.g. 60 is 1 away from 61 and 3 away from 63 on one side while it is also 1 away from 59 and 3 away from 57 on the other.

An odd number will conversely be an even offset from an odd composite or a prime.

I treat the odd and even cases separately.

To give this some meaning, I will try to explain what the following images represent.

Image 1 shows 0 and +-1 (mod 3)

Image 2 shows 0 , +-1 and +-2 (mod 5),

Image 3 shows 0, +-1, +-2 and +-3 (mod 7)

Take the number 60, it is 0 (mod 3) and so it is represented by the frame of **Image 1** that has a single red dot. That's because the set of odd numbers that are divisible by 3 either side of 60 can be represented by a single series of period 6 (it's 6 because the prime in question is 3, and we are only interested in odd composites).

Now take the number 62. It is 2 (mod 3) which is the same as -1 (mod 3). The odd numbers that are divisible by 3 either side of 62 cannot be represented by a single series of period 6, but *can* be represented by 2 such series out of phase by 1 with one another, as shown in the frame of **Image 1** with 2 red dots.

The number 64 is 1 (mod 3) and will be affected by the same pair of series as 62, hence the +-1 used to denote the pair of red dots.

Similar logic follows for mod 5, except in this case we have either a single series of period 10, 2 series of period 10 that are out of phase by 1, or 2 series of period 10 that are out of phase by 2 (or 3 depending on how you look at it) as depicted by the 3 frames of **Image 2**.

[image: 3 Mod 0,+-1] **Image 1**

[image: 5 Mod 0,+-1,+-2] **Image 2**

[image] **Image 3**

[image: Odd Sequence] **Image 4**

Now for **Image 4** and the reason behind my question.

I wrote a program to test the different permutations of the first n odd primes and find the longest possible sequences of composites either side of an odd or even number.

**Image 4** is a visual representation of the result I got for even numbers for the first 3 odd primes. My program shows that the longest sequence occurs for even numbers that are +-1 (mod 3) and +-1 (mod 5) and +-3 (mod 7). This is shown in the first 3 rows of **Image 4**.
Because this result is for even numbers, the red dots in the bottom row of **Image 4** are showing the odd columns for which a red dot appears in at least one of the first 3 rows. The black dot is the result. This represents the first guaranteed Goldbach Pair (for a number below $11^{2}$) - well maybe that's not 100% obvious but I have established that it's true.

In case you are wondering if I've lost the plot, I will make some practical sense of the result shown.

We can use the chinese remainder theorem to find even number solutions to the modular equations represented in **Image 4** (just for the sake of this example):

- x=+-1 (mod 3)
- x=+-1 (mod 5)
- x=+-3 (mod 7)

One such solution (chosen because it is within the range $7^{2}/2<n<11^{2}/2$) is **46**

Now testing for equidistant primes either side of **46** we find:

```
 {45,47} 45 is composite (Image 4 - row 4 - 1st red dot) 
 {43,49) 49 is composite (Image 4 - row 4 - 2nd red dot) 
 {41,51} 51 is composite (Image 4 - row 4 - 3rd red dot)
 {39,53} 39 is composite (Image 4 - row 4 - 4th red dot)
 {37,55} 55 is composite (Image 4 - row 4 - 5th red dot)
 {35,57} both composite  (Image 4 - row 4 - 6th red dot)
 {33,59} 33 is composite (Image 4 - row 4 - 7th red dot)
 {31,61} Bulls-eye, a Goldbach pair at 46 +-15 (Image 4 - row 4 - black dot).
```

This does not prove anything in itself, but it does I hope provide some meaning to **Image 4**.

I was able to compute that for the first 11 odd primes, the greatest position of the black square using odd columns is

3,9,**15**,33,75,87,105,165,213,255,339 **Series 1**

I also checked the even columns for the first 10 odd primes, and got

6,12,24,42,60,90,150,180,216,312 **Series 2**

NOTE - Image 4 is not appropriate for odd numbers because a different set of modular
equations is required: x = +-1 (mod 3); x= +-2 (mod 5) ; x = +-1 (mod 7). An appropriate solution for which is **43** which is +-24 from the nearest pair of equidistant primes {19,67} as predicted by the third element in **Series 2**

In case anyone is interested, one set of modular equations associated with **339** (the last member I have for Series 1) are

x=+-1 (mod 3); +-2 (mod 5); +-2 (mod 7); +-5 (mod 11); +-5 (mod 13); +-2 (mod 17); +-5 (mod 19); +-4 (mod 23); +-11 (mod 29); +-14 (mod 31); +-18 (mod 37)

I could not find any results on OEIS despite trying all variations of **Series 1** and **Series 2** that I could think of.

My question is, does anyone have any useful references, a formula (he said, not expecting an answer because it would probably prove Goldbach's strong conjecture) or an extension to the sequence(s) **Series 1** and **Series 2**?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "a potential composite number".

Comment: @Gerry Myerson - Sorry to throw that one in unexplained. I really meant that it was either a composite or the prime that gave rise to it. In contrast to the black-filled square that is definitely a prime. Sometimes there is a fine line between too much detail and not enough and maybe I got on the wrong side of it.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson - Actually the black-filled square represents a Goldbach Pair, oops.

Comment: OK, I'm almost beginning to understand what you have written. In image 4, in the 1st row, you've colored 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, and so on --- the numbers that are $\pm1$ modulo 3. In the second row, 1, 4, 6, 9, and so on --- $\pm1$ modulo 5. In the 3rd row, 3, 4, 10, 11, --- $\pm3$ modulo 7. And the smallest number that isn't in any of these residue classes is 15. And no other choice of residue classes gets past 15. I still don't understand what you mean by "odd columns" and/or "odd numbered columns".

Comment: I mean 1st 3rd 5th ... With the evens being 2nd 4th 6th ...

Comment: Ah.... So, in Image 4, the 12th column has no red, but you ignore that because it's an even number. So, what does the black square in column 15 have to do with Goldbach?

Comment: I'm going to attempt, again, to explain the relevance of this with a concrete example.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I would appreciate it if you could have another look now that I've made it clearer what column 15 means. There's also a numerical example demonstrating its significance. Please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is related to [A082467](https://oeis.org/A082467), Least $k>0$ such that $n-k$ and $n+k$ are both primes. A082467(46) = 15 corresponds to the pair $(46-15, 46+15)=(31,61)$ that you mention.

You may also be interested in [A129302](https://oeis.org/A129302), the worst-case numbers (or best case, if you're hoping for a counterexample).

Comment: Thanks Charles. I haven't established quite how relevant this is yet, but I can see that it is not totally unconnected at least. I will mark this up if I get nothing better, but I'm not sure if it's too late to award you the bounty.

Comment: _A082467_ is certainly of interest if only for confirmation of some of the numbers in my series.